# Studying sets and topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Looking for the limits points, the interior points, the closure and the boundary of the following sets.
 In  $R$ with the usual distance: {0, 1}, [0, 1) ∪ {2}, Z.
for {0,1} there are no limit points, no interior points, closed,no idea for the boundary , hints please?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x$ is a limit point of {0,1}, it means if $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ then $(U-{x})\cap \{0,1\}\neq \emptyset$. When  $x=0$, $x=1$,  $0<x<1$ or $1<x$ respectively say $U=(-1,0.5)$,  $U=(0.5,2)$ $U=(0,1)$ or $U=(1,x+1)$. Then got contradiction.

Suppose $x$ is a interior point of {0,1}. It means there exists an open interval $x\in$(a,b) such that (a,b)$\subset \{0,1\}$. This is contradicition.

Since $\mathbb{R}-\{0,1\}=(-\infty,0)\cup(0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$ is open, then {0,1} is closed.
Boundary of {0,1} is the set of closure points without interior points. Since {0,1} closed, closure of it is itself. Since interior of {0,1} emptyset. Then boundary of it is itself.